# pyodbc procedure execute failure

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms, pyodbc

I have an stored procedure on SQL Server (SSMS Studio)

This is the proc:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE  [dbo].[SELECT_main_program] (
     @name varchar(255))
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ed_programms.showing_name, ed_programms.scripts, ed_programms.styles, ed_programms.infos, ed_menu.*

    FROM ed_programms

    JOIN ed_menu
    ON ed_menu.id_program = ed_programms.id AND ed_menu.hidden = 0

    WHERE ed_programms.name = @name AND ed_programms.active = 1;
END
```

So if I call this proc the pyodbc returns the right row.

But if I call this proc there is an ERROR.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE  [dbo].[INSERT_ed_menu_program] (
    @name varchar(255),
    @showing_name varchar(255),
    @infos varchar(255),
    @scripts varchar(500),
    @styles varchar(500))
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ed_programms
    (name, showing_name, infos, scripts, styles, active)
    VALUES(@name, @showing_name, @infos, @scripts, @styles, 1)
END
```

Here is my python code.

```py
# Create the procedure params.
params = ", ".join(['?' for i, row in enumerate(list(call[1]))])
variables = ", ".join([row for i, row in enumerate(list(call[1]))])
sql = "EXEC {sp} {prms}".format(sp=call[0], prms=params)

# Check if is an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE.
if call[0][0].upper() == "I" or call[0][0].upper() == "U" or call[0][0].upper() == "D":
    return stmt.execute(sql, [variables]).commit()
else:
    return stmt.execute(sql, [variables]).fetchall()
```

The variable `call` is an list and holds the name of the proc and the params.

So the question is why is my code working if I execute the select proc. But not working if I execute the insert proc?

The Error is

```sql
INSERT_ed_menu_program The SQL contains 5 parameter markers but 1 parameters were supplied HY000
```

UPDATE 2: The printed SQL is

```py
sql = EXEC INSERT_ed_menu_program ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
variables = my_program, Mein Test 01, test 01 desc, ,
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: The error is pretty clear. 5 parameters were defined but only a single text parameter with a very weird content was passed. SQL parameters aren't format specifiers. They *don't* just replace the markers. If they did, they wouldn't protect from SQL injection, or avoid formatting errors. You need to pass the individual parameter values

Comment: And how can I get the parameter names? The only thing I now is the name of the procedure in this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finaly I have an solution for this.

Here are my solution:
I have removes the code section `variables` in MSSQL this is not supported.
I overgive the list with the `variables` diractly to the execute statement.

Like this:

```py
return stmt.execute(sql, call[1]).commit()
```

Thanks [@Panagiotis Kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos)